# Can Retrofit generate query parameters with the same name in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, parameters, retrofit

I came across to make this type of request:
I need to map `List<int>ids` query parameter `id` like this:

`/api/available-specialists?id=3176&id=3170`

And is it possible to make this request even without retrofit in dart?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

1. In the place, where you create your Dio instance, update ListFormat if needed. `BaseOptions(listFormat: ListFormat.multi)`. ListFormat.multi is default value and it helps to convert your list of params into string like this: foo=value&foo=another_value. In my case everything works without updating ListFormat.
2. In the repository, where you define your methods, specify your Query:

   `@Query('status') List<int> statusList,`
3. Run `flutter pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs` then re-run your app.
4. When you make the request, you can see such url in logs: `https://some-api/end-point/?status=2&status=4`